# On Windows 10 in GitBash, how do I configure ag (silver searcher) to print out the file where a string occurs?

Tags: windows-10, search, git-bash

I'm using GitBash on Windows 10.  I want to use the silver searcher (ag), which I have used on *-nix systems and I have this installed in GitBash

```
$ ag --version
ag version 2.2.5 ; Windows port 2021-06-04 Win64 >= Server2003 amd64
MsvcLibX 2021-06-03 ; PCRE 8.44 2020-02-12 ; pthreads4w 3.0.0 ; zlib 1.2.11

Features:
  +jit -lzma +zlib +2enc
```

However, when I use the utility in GitBash, it doesn't print out the file in which the search string occurs,

$ echo 'hello' > /tmp/file

```
MYUSER@ABCDEf XYZGW64 ~/Documents/workspace/finance-uimodule-customersetup (dev/POAWS-3048_part2)
$ ag 'hello' /tmp
hello
```

How do I configure silver searcher (ag) so that when I do a search it prints out the file where the actual string occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it with the `winpty` command:

```
    winpty ag 'hello' /tmp
```

Ref.: https://gist.github.com/DeanPDX/acff533cff0cfbda2761d1e62e8cb1a7#getting-npm-colors--progress-working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain the command with your words instead of just linking a random page thatmay disappear whenever.